# Is there any way, any way at all, a Word document could become a PNG? (Probable case of cheating)

Tags: ms-word, png, corrupt

I think a student of mine renamed a PNG a Word document and intentionally submitted a corrupted file to buy more time (or something) on an assignment. The student denies everything and claims it was a computer malfunction. Before I submit an honor code violation I want to be sure that there's no explanation that does *not* involve cheating that I'm somehow overlooking.

Basically, I'm a TA and a student submitted a paper, let's say it was Smith.docx. When I was working on grading and went to open Smith.docx Word wouldn't open it and said that it was corrupted. I eventually had the idea of opening it in a text editor and there it was a massive jumbled file of all sorts of odd characters (total file size: 180kb for what was supposed to be a 5 page paper).

I noticed, though, that the first few characters of the file were: 
‰PNG

I renamed the file Smith.png and it opened. Bizarrely, it was an image of the first page of a Word document. More specifically, it looks like a screenshot of a Word doc cropped so as to show just the page. What makes it seem like a screenshot is that the cursor thingy (the vertical bar marking where you're typing) shows up next to the title.

An additional interesting bit of data is that if I scroll further down in the file (opened in notepad) I come to this:

```
XML:com.adobe.xmp     <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.4.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
         <exif:PixelXDimension>996</exif:PixelXDimension>
         <exif:PixelYDimension>1286</exif:PixelYDimension>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

I'm not sure what all that means but 1286x996 are the dimensions of the png image. The rest suggests to me that the file was created in some Adobe program but I'm not sure if that's right and how to figure out more about that.

So, my actual question: Is there any conceivable explanation of any kind for how I would come to have a file called Smith.docx that is a perfectly functioning png of what sure looks like a screenshot of the first page of a Word document *other* than that the student did it on purpose? The student claimed that their computer was "corrupting" files and that they had to take it into the Apple for service. I find this incredibly implausible (student has also not provided the receipt for this, which I requested).

Additionally, other than the case I laid out here, is there any positive evidence for my theory (that it was a straightforward case of cheating) that I can present to strengthen my case? eg, is the data from the file that I posted above a smoking gun that it was created in an Adobe program or is there any conceivable way that could come out of a Word document or other sort of corrupted file?

Also, is there anything else I can look for in the PNG file that would be a smoking gun?

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer!

Comment: Obviously he took a screenshot, renamed it to .docx, and submitted it.  The XMP stuff means he used some Adobe product to take the screenshot. I can't imagine how that would happen accidentally.  I don't know if Adobe sells a Word product or if MS Word has an Adobe plugin of some sort; I use OpenOffice and that doesn't have a "save as PNG" capability.

Comment: P.S. Google "MS Word PNG" turns up a few plugins/toolbars whatnot that would enable a person to save a document as a PNG.  But as others have said, there's a nonzero but very small chance that it was an accident.  Changing the extension to .docx had to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

just rename the file with .png at the end instead of .docx and if it was a png then it should open just fine as a png

Comment: Right, I've renamed it .png and it opens as what appears to be a screenshot of the first page of a word doc. What I'm wondering is if there's any conceivable explanation for this other than someone intentionally renaming a png as a .docx.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you see the cursor in the screenshot, there is no way Word would export (somehow) a docx file as a png AND draw the cursor for typing. Also, any tool that could do that would save the file as png not docx, only the user could deliberately change the file extension.

Also, does the screenshot show an empty document? or it looks like the final document your student delivered at the end?

Comment: Not a blank document--has nearly verbatim the text that was in the paper the student eventually sent. That's part of what's so weird to me about the whole case.

Comment: Well, I must say I was expecting a funny image when you renamed the file :). Anyway, the computer didn't change the file by itself, the two possibilities I see: 99.9% he is cheating, 0.1% he somehow confused the save dialog to some image export method and renamed the file as a docx in the save dialog (so it was human mistake). Maybe should be 99.99% against 0.01% though...

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

The student is lying and is in fact a cheater (in my opinion).

Also, even if they were telling the truth, it is still their responsibility to have their work done, ready, and fully functional on time. Your computer is corrupting your files? Tough cookies. No one cares. You should have done your work on another computer. In the real world, excuses don't get you anywhere and they shouldn't get you anywhere in school either.

Lastly, it is very easy to re-name an extension of another file type and claim it's corrupt and very unlikely that a computer is just creating corrupted files. If their computer would otherwise create corrupted files, I would imagine it would be nearly impossible to get the computer to boot. In other words, they probably wouldn't have been able to turn on their "corrupted" computer to create "corrupted" files in the first place.

Comment: I am the downvoter.  The edited answer is better but still the first sentence is stating an opinion, not a fact.  OP is looking for facts to back up his own opinion.  "I think the student is lying and is very likely to be a cheater" would be more accurate, and in fact I'd agree with that.

Comment: I attempted to undownvote but looks like I did it wrong.  Will try again tomorrow.